# NoSuchElementException can't be thrown

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use an element for testing and I want to continue the test if the element even couldn't be found.

I used NoSuchElementException for this part of my codes.

Here is what I've tried before:

```
try {
    WebElement site_width_full_width = wait.until( 
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
            By.cssSelector("label[for=site_width-full_width]")));
    site_width_full_width.click();

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("FullWidth Label Found!");

} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("FullWidth Label not found!");
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

But when the element isn't available it can't be thrown into the NoSuchElementException and all test breaks and fails.

What's the solution and how could I continue the test when the element isn't available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is throwing a `NoSuchElementException` the behaviour when an element can not be found?

Comment: It shows me this error:
Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"label[for=site_width-full_width]"}

For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

That's the reason i used this exception @Smutje

Comment: Right before that "Unable to locate element" message is the name of the exception that's thrown... what is it? That's what you need to catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be getting the exception of a different derived class type. You can catch it using the parent class 'Exception' and then further drill down the exact exception type.

try using;

```
try
{
            WebElement site_width_full_width = wait.until(
                    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                    By.cssSelector("label[for=site_width-full_width]")));
            site_width_full_width.click();

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("FullWidth Label Found!");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e instanceof NoSuchElementException)
            {
                System.out.println("FullWidth Label not found!");
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Unexpected exception!");
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with its parent classes like Throwable or Exception in catch block. In my case, I am Throwable in catch block which works as expected

Comment: Exception class worked fine, thank you. But I'm still wondering why its specific class (NoSuchElement) doesn't work. @Sreenivasulu

Comment: You could try to debug and set a breakpoint in the catch-block, then you could of which class the caught Exception is.

Comment: @AliMozafari You can refer this page for more information regarding these exception hierarchy. https://github.com/selenide/selenide/issues/218.  Refer the comments made by kenston on Aug 17, 2016. Its just an hierarchy issue

Answer (score 0):

You are catching a `NoSuchElementException`, but an explicit wait throws a `TimeoutException` if nothing is found.  To get what you have working you should modify your code to do the following:

```
    try {
        WebElement site_width_full_width = wait.until(
                ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                        By.cssSelector("label[for=site_width-full_width]")
                ));
        site_width_full_width.click();
        System.out.println("FullWidth Label Found!");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException | TimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("FullWidth Label not found!");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

However using Try/Catch for execution flow is generally a code anti-pattern.  You would be much better off doing something like this:

```
    List<WebElement> site_width_full_width = 
            driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("label[for=site_width-full_width]"));
    if (site_width_full_width.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("FullWidth Label Found!");
        site_width_full_width.get(0).click();
    } else {
        System.out.println("FullWidth Label not found!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver already provide the way to deal this problem in much simpler way. you can use following way

```
 WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException), typeof(ElementNotVisibleException));

 WebElement site_width_full_width = wait.until( 
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
            By.cssSelector("label[for=site_width-full_width]")));
    site_width_full_width.click();

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("FullWidth Label Found!");
```

Note : You can add all types of exception need to be ignored.